# Gitlab - Push with to remote not working

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I installed Gitlab 6 on my MBP running OS X 10.8.5 and works fine.  I can create projects, users, commit, push ... But only from there.

I try to push project from my iMac ( I do git config, init, add, commit), I generated also the ssh keys.
When a test the connection : ssh -T git@my_server it gives "Welcome to Gitlab, Anonymous".
but when I issue the push -u origin master I've got :

> Blockquote
>   Access denied
>   Fatal: Could not read from remote repository
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
>   Blockquote

Is it something relating with SSH or with Gitlab itself ?
In Gitlab 6 a added  a 2d key to the project, my public key (generated on the iMac).
On my MBP I added the content of the id_rsa.pub (iMac) to the authorised_keys and known_hosts files (MBP)

Thank.

Comment: If I type "ssh git@my_Server I get PTY allocation request failed on channel 0"  connection closed...